# Radio and checkbox cannot be checked when inside BootStrap Modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that needs to have both radio´s and checkboxes, and when I place the below code outside the Modal they work as expected, but as soon as I move them inside the modal I am not able to check/choose them .. I am using Bootstrap v. 4.6.0.

The Radio button code:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Pension" id="PensionYES" value="yes" CHECKED>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="PensionYES">Ja</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Pension" id="PensionNO" value="no">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="PensionNO">Nej</label>
</div>
```

I did find a hack that works, using jQuery, but that does not work when CHECKED has been preset, also I am uncertain if it will work when submitting the form (if the chosen value is transmitted) .. and lastly I think this is a weird behavior, I should not need to use jQuery for this to work.

The temporary hack:

```
<script>
jQuery(".modal input:checkbox,.modal label").on("click", function(e)
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var element = (e.currentTarget.htmlFor !== undefined) ? e.currentTarget.htmlFor : e.currentTarget;
    var checked = (element.checked) ? false : true;
    element.checked = (checked) ? false : checked.toString();
});
jQuery(".modal input:radio,.modal label").on("click", function(e)
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var element = (e.currentTarget.htmlFor !== undefined) ? e.currentTarget.htmlFor : e.currentTarget;
    var checked = (element.checked) ? false : true;
    element.checked = (checked) ? false : checked.toString();
});
</script>
```

Anyone who can help with a good solution for this? :-)

Best Regards

Stig

Comment: Hi, please elaborate more on your problem .

Comment: Hi Swati .. what more info do you need elaborated? .. as stated the radio and check boxes works when I use them on the same page as the Modal, but outside the Modal, if I move them inside the modal I can click on them, but nothing happens, in other words they do not get selected .. I have tried to start a plain standard Bootstrap page with 4.6.0 and a standard plain Modal with check boxes and radio´s, and even though it is stripped of all exept standard HTML5 and standard CDN Bootstrap 4.6.0 CSS/jQuery it still not work.

Comment: I just pasted your code on a Modal ' Try it Yourself ' example at w3school.com and it works. It means the fault is somewhere else; e.g. the header code

Comment: Hmm .. yes, you are right, it works at www.w3schools.com in "their try it your self"  .. I will try to dig into that tomorrow morning - I will get back :-)

Comment: I have now testet in my environment, changing to default described document header, but that does not work .. only thing that makes the radi/check boxes work in the Modal part of my page is if I remove either the CDN Link to CSS or the CDN Link to JS .. any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4-5 days of testing in my 2.024 line long page code, I finally found the reason why neighther checkboxes, radios and HREF´s did not work in the page .. reason : a damn JavaScript .. here is what blocked the mouse interaction:

```
<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".show", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
    return false;
  });
</script>
```